# Is きっさてん one or two words in romaji?

Tags: translation, word-choice, hiragana, rōmaji

I realize I should not be spending too much time with romaji but I would like to try and understand more about how to translate hiragana to romaji. I used a translation web page and I noticed it sometimes adds spaces.

With the revised Hepburn system is this word translated like this:  kisaten or kisa ten? If the later then can someone explain why.

Similar question:  そうじ

Should this appear as Sō ji or  Sōji

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

きっさてん is commonly referred to as kissaten, see [Kissaten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissaten). Please note that there are two S because of the small つ, which creates an extended /s/ sound.

For そうじ, I am assuming you mean the suru verb. I would write "sōji" since it is all one word, not separate words.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Can you explain a bit more about a glottal stop?  Just 1-2 line about it would be a big help.

Comment: Yes. In Japanese, when you see the small っ (chiisai tsu), it means you have to make a short kind of break in the word at that location. For example, in kissaten, instead of four syllables "ki sa te n", you should say five syllables: "ki ss sa te n". I would imagine a kind of snake sound to hold the s for one syllable.
In other words, like だった (datta) instead of "da ta", you should say "da (short break) ta"

Comment: @Alan, Please watch this video–I think it would be very beneficial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVynW7frBig

Comment: It's actually neither glottal not a stop.  Instead, it is a long /s/ sound.

Comment: @snailplane Thank you for pointing that out. Since in cases such as だった and 待って it is a glottal stop, I just had it in my mind that it was a glottal stop.

Comment: @Griffen It's not a glottal stop in だった. It is an [alveolar stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_stop). A glottal stop occurs deep in the throat, like when you say "uh-oh!".